# How can I pass values from all text fields from View Controller to Model class to decouple model logic from it?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller

I want to move logic that creates new object or existing one from view controller save action and pass it some way to the model for parsing. View has about ten fields of data that need to be passed. Now my save method has more than 60 lines of which at least 40 should be moved to model class.

I was thinking about creating dictionary of type `[String: Any?]` to catch all fields and then pass it to model's method but I am not sure if this is valid way?

Can I ask you for recommendations?

Comment: Not sure where you're going to save this data, but with Matia's `struct`, you could could conform the struct to `Codable` and you'd be able to encode it to save it somewhere.

Comment: I make it Codable and save to JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your way is valid but I think you don't need a dictionary. Just add a parser method that receives the text fields as parameters and has the logic to create the model.

Let's say you have a Person model:

```
class Person {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }

    static func parse(firstName: String, lastName: String) -> Person {
        // Add here the required logic
        return Person(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName)
    }
}
```

And then in your view controller you can just do:

```
let person = Person.parse(firstName: firstNameTextField.text, lastName: lastNameTextField.text)
```

---

EDIT:

You can use a struct too and get rid of the init

```
struct Person {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String

    static func parse(firstName: String, lastName: String) -> Person {
        // Add here the required logic
        return Person(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName)
    }
}
```

Comment: You could turn it into a struct and ditch the initializer.

Comment: parse method will have 10+ parameters ... that is what I want to avoid ...

Comment: @PawełMadej If you use a dictionary then you need to do unnecessary work to create the dictionary and read the keys on the parser method. 
I don't see a problem on having many parameters, but if you don't want to have 10+ parameters in one parser, you can create different parser methods that each of them groups logically some kind of parameters that have something in common (in the case this make sense to your model parameters)

Comment: I tried to avoid such huge parser due to one of SwiftLint rules that "prohibits" such use case. but maybe in this situation this could be way to go to decouple VC from model logic. This is my first project which already hit App Store but I try to clean the code to make it testable.

Comment: @PawełMadej maybe the solution is refactor the models, separate them in different models and have one "main" model that will have the instances of the "new" models. But again, this depends on your business rules and logic.